# Is it possible to retrain Google's Universal Sentence Encoder such that it takes keywords into account when encoding sentences?

Tags: python, nlp, tensorflow-hub, sentence-similarity

I am a bit confused on what it means to set `trainable = True` when loading the Universal Sentence Encoder 3. I have a small corpus (3000 different sentences), given a sentence I want to find the 10 most similar sentences.
My current method is:

1) Load the module
`embed = hub.Module("path", trainable =False)`

2) Encode all sentences:
 `session.run(embed(sentences))`

3) Find the closest sentences using cosine similarity.

It performs decent, but I would want the model to be finetuned to my own dictionary, becuase there are certain keywords which are more important than others. This is thus not a classification problem. When looking at the existing examples for retrainin the module (https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/text_classification_with_tf_hub) it is for classification.

Is it possible to make the Universal Sentence Encoder retrain on my keywords and output different embeddings (for instance by setting `trainable = True`)?

Answer (score 2):

Setting `hub.Module(..., trainable=True)` does not allow to change the vocabulary but it makes the module's variables trainable, which may be enough to capture a chance in relevance of existing words.

Pre-trained word embeddings like U.S.E. tend to be useful for a variety of tasks (including classification, regression, proximity search in the embedding space). Generally speaking, there's nothing wrong starting with the same TF Hub modules for any of these.

**EDIT:** See also https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/355